# Access ignoring default printer settings

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, printing, microsoft-access

I have several Access programs, they're fairly complex, lots of VBA in them and dozens of reports, linked tables, etc.  When I print these reports, they don't respect my default printer settings (namely, the duplex option).  How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the `.UseDefaultPrinter` property of the report to `True`.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139946%28office.10%29.aspx), this code will reset the printer of all reports to default:

```
For Each obj In CurrentProject.AllReports
    DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:=obj.Name, View:=acViewDesign
    If Not Reports(obj.Name).UseDefaultPrinter Then
        Reports(obj.Name).UseDefaultPrinter = True
        DoCmd.Save ObjectType:=acReport, ObjectName:=obj.Name
    End If
    DoCmd.Close
Next obj
```

Comment: Where should I put this code?  In autoexec?

Comment: it can be put into autoexec, or as a separate piece of code that can be run at anytime.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this exact problem and fixed it by setting the report's `.Printer` property to the default printer (or desired printer) before printing as below.

```
'need report open in order to set .Printer property
'  so open report in PREVIEW mode but HIDDEN
DoCmd.OpenReport "<ReportName>", acViewPreview, , , acHidden
'Assign report's .Printer property to default printer
Reports("<ReportName>").Printer = Application.Printers(Printer.DeviceName)
'Print report
DoCmd.OpenReport "<ReportName>", acViewNormal
```